# input cannot be resolved : Using Scanner class and Array

Tags: java, javascript, android

import java.util.Scanner;
class Arrayy
{

```
public static void main(String a[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    double arr[] = new double[5];
    for (int i = 1 ; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter The Stuff: ");     
        arr[i] = **input**.nextInt();

    }
}
}
```

The place where i have marked bold shows an exception that "input cannot be resolved"

can someone please help, although its very basic.

Comment: You never define input. use sc.nextInt()

Answer (score 2):

Your Scanner variable is called `sc`, not `input`.

```
public static void main(String a[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    double arr[] = new double[5];
    for (int i = 1 ; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter The Stuff: ");     
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

    }
}
```